# How to add unique ID to each group and subgroup within each group in two different column in pandas dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Expected output as below:i am using below for book id but not sure how to get class id
df1['Books_id']=df1.groupby('Books').ngroup()

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the DataFrame? (Input and expected output)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.